# selenium webdriver error when searching by.id.

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium, and this is my first webdriver code using java.
I am trying to open google page and search for seleniumhq.org.
My question is - when I check for a element using its name, the code works perfectly and the same code if i change it to find an element by its id. I get an error message as "exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions"

Kindly help me to understand this issue.
    package com.webdriver.chapter1;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class NavigateToUrl {

public static void main(String[] args) {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0"));
//System.out.println(searchBox.getText());
//List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.className("gsfi"));
//System.out.println(buttons.size());
searchBox.sendKeys("seleniumhq.org");
searchBox.submit();
//WebElement aboutLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Videos"));
//aboutLink.click();
```

}
}

Comment: aholts answer is correct. The way you find the right ID is to navigate to the page and right-click on the desired element (when possible) and choose Inspect element. The dev toolbar of the browser should open up and select the element. You can then look for the correct ID and use it. I prefer Chrome because of all the features it has. I would strongly recommend that you find your favorite browser and watch or read some tutorials on how to use the dev tools of that browser. It will help you immensely when coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What that error is telling you, is that the element you are selecting by ID, is disabled on the webpage.

A quick look at the HTML structure of google.co.in tells me that the element you are trying to select is, in fact, disabled:

```
<input class="gsfi" 
    disabled="" 
    autocomplete="off" 
    aria-hidden="true" 
    id="gs_htif0" dir="ltr" 
    style="border: none; 
        padding: 0px; 
        margin: 0px; 
        height: auto; 
        width: 100%; 
        position: absolute; 
        z-index: 1; 
        -webkit-text-fill-color: silver; 
        color: silver; 
        transition: all 0.218s; 
        -webkit-transition: all 0.218s; 
        opacity: 0; 
        text-align: left; 
        left: 0px; 
        background-color: transparent;">
```

You should select the non-disabled element, whose id is:  "lst-ib"